# "sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1" doesn't work on macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, network-programming, macos-sierra

I am trying to get the Apple sample "SimpleTunnel" to work between iOS and macOS. One of the steps required "sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1" but apparently this command terminated with an error "sysctl: unknown oid 'net.inet.ip.fw.enable'" in macOS Sierra.

Is there a replacement command or is this command not required anymore? Anyway, I tried to continue without the command but couldn't establish the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Yosemite (10.10) and going forward, IPFW is no longer available on OS. You have to use [PF](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) software to setup your firewall instead.

There is a discussion about it [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6645172).